# Jqgrid formatter rowboject is undefined while update

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am here tring to update some rowobject in formatter according to second jqgrid value but while update it show like "undefined".how to resolve this ??

```
                        name:'xx',
                        index:'xx',
                        classes:'xx',
                        width:120,
                        align:'center',
                        sorttype: 'String',
                formatter:function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) 
                            {

                            return "<div style='color:red'><center>"+rowObject.xx+ "(Click here to View Patta Dhaar Details)</center></div>";   

                            }

function dd()
{
var v = JSON.parse(document.getElementById("xx"+sno).innerHTML);
var newpatta=v.curpatta;
var newsurveynewNo=v.surveynewNo;

var currrow= $("#currpattachk").val();

alert("am getting value here"+v.xx);

var cm =  $("#land_details_table_new").getGridParam('colModel');

var rowData = $("#land_details_table_new").getRowData(currrow);

$("#land_details_table_new").jqGrid('setCell', currrow, 'curPatta', v.xx);

$("#land_details_table_new").jqGrid('getLocalRow', currrow).xx = v.xx;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but it's unclear what you want. The function `dd` will be not called. What is `#currpattachk`? If you want to display specific value in `curPatta` then you can use custom formatter in the column `curPatta`. If you need **to modify** the data you should do this *before* displaying the data. For example if you load the data from the server then you can modify the server response inside of `beforeProcessing` callback.

Comment: var currrow= $("#currpattachk").val(); it is my hidden row index by this i am getting nth row and in that i am trying to  particular column value that is xx column while update it show undefined

Comment: Sorry, but can't follow you absolutely. 1) `rowObject` can't be `undefined` 2) row index is the ordinal number of *every row*. So "hidden row index" can't be and it can't be saved in *one* field ` $("#currpattachk")`. You use not common terminology. So it's difficult to understand what you mean. I thnink that you should include more full code which you use or better to provide the demo which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: kindly ignore before comment check this image http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=23vl501&s=8#.VUtHsPbI-lM  first on load 
http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=161lri9&s=8#.VUtFp_bI-lN second click and kindly help on this

Comment: It looks like `rowObject.xx` is undefined and **not**  `rowObject` like you wrote in your question. If `rowObject` is undefined then you will get null exception in `rowObject.xx`. You still don't answer where you call `dd` function and which relation it has to your question. Which code you use to create jqGrid? Some options (`datatype`, `loadonce` and other) could be very important for understanding the problem. Which test data and in which format you use to fill the grid? It's better you provide **the demo** which reproduces the problem. Which version of jqGrid you use?

Comment: By the way you can go at the end of your previous comment. You will see `x` button after the time stamp (something like "12 mins ago"). By click on `x` button you can remove your old comment.

Comment: mine version is jqGrid  4.7.1 if u saw on second image u saw a radio button for ever radio click (dd) action wil take place and i used to fill  a json type data and then i use (data:local)

Comment: Can you provide the demo which reproduces the problem?

Comment: sorry for those which i made i found instead for rowobject i used a cellvalue its work now thanks for u r patience